# Net::OpenSSH error handling

Tags: perl, ssh, error-handling, openssh

I need my code to handle every kind or error that can be thrown by the [`Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) module. I can't figure out how to do this using the [`$ssh->error`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH#Error-handling) function.

For example :

```
switch ($ARGV[2]) {
case "OBS" {
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$user:$passwdobs\@$ARGV[1]");
    $ssh->error and die "echec ssh : " . $ssh->error;
    }
}
```

This code gives me error messages like this:

```
ssh: connect to host 126.120.180.250 port 22: Connection refused
echec ssh : unable to establish master SSH connection: bad password 
     or master process exited unexpectedly at sshscript.pl line 26.
```

These two error messages have nothing in common, the first tells me the real reason, and the second tells me WHO failed (the master ssh connection).  It seems the only errors that OpenSSH can throw are the constants listed here: [`Net::OpenSSH::Constants`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aConstants)

I would like my script to let me know *why* my connections failed, so I can send the errors to a database with the help of a separate `ssh_error.sql` file. Is this possible with OpenSSH module ?

Comment: Hi @Gia, this is a good question - hopefully you will get an answer that helps. The POD says: "Most methods return `undef` (or an empty list) to indicate failure. The "`error`" method can always be used to explicitly check for errors." - which suggests you have to write explicit checks for each kind of failure. Can you use capture the system error text instead?

Comment: Hi,
You mean redirect the STDERR to STDOUT and check for words like "network unreachable" or "connection timed out" or "connection refused" ?

Comment: Oops I meant @Gui O earlier .. yes that is what I meant: either by filtering in the code itself or just adding that kind of thing to the SQL statements you then use to work with the data you're collecting. The easiest way would be if `->error` could do some of that for us, but skimming through the [module source](https://metacpan.org/source/SALVA/Net-OpenSSH-0.62/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) I don't see a built-in exported method for doing what you want.

Comment: @salva might be able to help :-)

Comment: When `ssh` fails to establish the connection it doesn't tell Net::OpenSSH the cause of the failure. That's the reason you get generic error messages. A workaround is to redirect the master stderr stream to a file (`master_stderr_fh`) and when something fails, read and postprocess it in Perl.

Comment: I guess i have to open another thread to ask how to do that ?

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH/blob/master/sample/save_master_error.pl)!

Comment: @salva this is great (+1) - not surprising that `Net::OpenSSH` can already do this **:-)**  I suggest you post it as an answer so @Gui O can accept it (and then maybe cut and paste some of it - and the sample code - into the POD for `master_stdout_fh` `master_stderr_fh`). Oh and **thanks** for `Net::Openssh` !

Comment: oh ... and for `Sort::Key` but that is OT :-)